# How to make a desktop shortcut for live session user

Tags: 20.04, live-usb, ubiquity, custom-distributions

I am trying to make my own linux distro based on Ubuntu, and have a different desktop enviroment installed. This desktop enviroment (KDE) does not show Ubiquity in the applications by default, so I want to put the shortcut on the desktop, but I only want this for the live session user, and not for the other users, so putting the shortcut in /etc/skel/Desktop won't work (also for other users) How can I make sure it's only for the live session user and not for anybody else?

I'm using the Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop ISO btw

Comment: One assumes you have already made a *persistent* LiveUSB. Else you cannot make any changes anyway. Next, since a Live session has no login, what other user would there be? And how would you enforce that user is on their correct account?

Comment: I have an ISO made by Cubic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach is to actually create the launcher in the `skel` folder, but then automatically delete this launcher after the OS installation has completed successfully.

1. **Create the launcher**

   Execute the following in Cubic's Terminal page:

   ```
    mkdir /etc/skel/Desktop
    cp /usr/share/applications/ubiquity.desktop /etc/skel/Desktop/
    chmod +x /etc/skel/Desktop/ubiquity.desktop
    ls -la /etc/skel/Desktop/*
   ```
2. **Delete the launcher after installation**

   On Cubic's Options page, click the Preseed tab, and add the following at the end of the `ubuntu.seed` file:

   ```
    ubiquity ubiquity/success_command string \
        in-target bash -c 'rm -rf /etc/skel/Desktop/ubiquity.desktop'; \
        in-target bash -c 'rm -rf /home/*/Desktop/ubiquity.desktop';
   ```

Comment: I actually like this approach, I will try it out when I have time

Comment: I still can't find it on my desktop, but at least it shows up in the correct folder...

Comment: Okay, I found it, just need some more modding to the shortcut